# Static SQL Methods pros and cons

Tags: asp.net

In one of labs I was doing the static methods for SQL, but once I was told that this practice is bad because of memory access error. The man who told me this has motivated it this way:

> You can't do the sql methods static because if they are static are living in stack. And every method who living in stack has address like 0X0001. What if many users will point the same method in the same time? An access error will happen.

I tried to tell him about pooling in ASP.Net, but there was no need cos he was so much sure. But now this issue sits in my brains. What if it's true what he said me, or was this man just pulling my leg?

Comment: He's talking crap - really a method that gets called too many times will cause an access error!?  Never a good sign when someone is so sure of themselves they won't listen.

Comment: He was that sure even about the methods that involve any kind of sqlcommands.

Comment: Yea - all method calls get pushed onto the stack, regardless of it's sql content or not - so his comments still don't make sense

Comment: this guy is Chief of crew (programmers)

Comment: I think you should show him this thread and get him to comment.  You may have mis-quoted him

Comment: no need it's ok. it was just not so pleasure to here about a couple of minutes how much idiot I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each web request is handled by a separate thread, I fail to see how having a static method could cause a problem:  Each thread has it's own stack.

Static variables....now THOSE could cause a problem!

Comment: Please, tell me more about these issues with static variables.